# Is there an org.apache.hadoop.fs.modifyAclEntries feature for recursively modifying the children directories acl

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm using CDH version CDH 5.13.3, hadoop-2.6.0, spark-2.3.0. Spark job creates a directory with children directories By A user, then I want to modify the directory and children directories's acl, so B user can access them. But now B user can only access the parent directory and can not access children directories

```scala
def modifyAcl(fs: FileSystem, pathStr: String, aclSpec: String, 
              includePermission: Boolean) = {
    try {
      val path = new Path(pathStr)

      println(s"acl print: ${fs.getAclStatus(path)}")

      fs.modifyAclEntries(path, AclEntry.parseAclSpec(aclSpec, includePermission))

      println(s"new acl print: ${fs.getAclStatus(path)}")
    } catch {
      case ex: UnsupportedOperationException =>
        ex.printStackTrace()
      case e: IOException =>
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
      fs.close()
    }
  }
```

the log output:
acl print: owner: infinivision_kylo_user, group: supergroup, acl: {entries: [], stickyBit: false}

new acl print: owner: infinivision_kylo_user, group: supergroup, acl: {entries: [default:user::rwx, default:user:hongtaozhang:rwx, default:group::r-x, default:mask::rwx, default:other::---], stickyBit: false}